# NumPy - cumulative dot product with a special choice of elements, no loops

Tags: python, numpy

I have two vectors a=(a1, ..., a_n) and b=(b_1, ..., b_n), and I want to build vector c such that

c_(k) = a_(1)b_(n-k+1) + a_(2)b_(n-k+2) + ... + a_(k)b_(n)

For example, for vectors `a=[1, 2, 3, 4]`, `b=[5, 6, 7, 8]` I'm expecting to get:

`c = [1*8, 1*7+2*8, 1*6+2*7+3*8, 1*5+2*6+3*7+4*8] = [8, 23, 44, 70]`

Is there a way to do this with just numpy, without using loops?

**Example with loops**

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
b = np.array([5, 6, 7, 8])
c = []
for i in range(1, len(a) + 1):
    c.append(a[:i].dot(b[-i:]))
c = np.array(c) # [ 8 23 44 107]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This operation is the convolution of `a` and the reversed `b`. In numpy you can use [`np.convolve`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html) to do this. You seem to want a special case where you take the first N elements, where N is the length of `a` (or `b`, since I assume they're both the same length). This is nonstandard, so I just index the first N elements. Typically, you would use one of the convolution modes, such as `"full"` (default), `"same"`, or `"valid"` (these are explained in the documentation).

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
b = np.array([5, 6, 7, 8])

c = np.convolve(a, b[::-1])[:a.shape[0]]
print(c)  # [ 8 23 44 70]
```

If you have a much larger dataset, an FFT-based convolution method will be faster. So, as per the documentation, you would use [`scipy.signal.fftconvolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.fftconvolve.html#scipy.signal.fftconvolve).

```py
from scipy.signal import fftconvolve

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
b = np.array([5, 6, 7, 8])

c = fftconvolve(a, b[::-1])[:a.shape[0]]
print(c)  # [ 8. 23. 44. 70.]
```